# Security of hardware encrypted HDD's?

Tags: external-hard-drive, encryption

E.g.: 
http://shop.lenovo.com/SEUILibrary/controller/e/gbweb/LenovoPortal/en_GB/catalog.workflow:item.detail?GroupID=38&Code=57Y4400

My Opinions: 

 - Are there any hardware encrypted HDD's that has a LED interface? (LED numpad is needed to output the numbers in a random place - so that if heat cams still see what I typed - the numbers, e.g.: "1" will be at other place every time it gets plugged in power - e.g. not in the bottom-left corner, e.g.: in the top left)

 - Numbers are enough for password? Are there any encrypted drives that could have a better pass? E.g.: not just numbers like the mentioned link... - 16 char password max?? If counting: If I could try 100000 combination/sec I can try all the combinations in 127 days!! that's not such a big number.....using only numbers are not a good idea.

 - Does it needs any drivers? If I install an OpenBSD on it, and want to boot from it (to use as Desktop PC), will it work?

Thank you for you're opinions, answers. (which encrypted drive to choose? which one is the safest?)

Comment: Shopping/buying recommendations are off topic.

Comment: Agreed with @timbooo, in its current form you're asking for a buying recommendation. But maybe you can rewrite the question to be a bit more general, concerning safety of encrypted hard drives.

Comment: Heat cameras? Wow... Why not tap a few invalid keys if you are that worried?

Comment: Well, what kind of 'threat' do you have where you need to worry about people with heatcams, and days to try things? If you NEED that kind of security, you probably have boffins to do it for you. And that kind of security means you are still vulnerable to wrench cryptography http://xkcd.com/538/

Answer (score 2):

if you are really worrying about others putting relatively advanced intelligence technologies onto your living environment, what you need will be much more than a mere encrypted harddrive. For your purpose, you may as well want to make sure your computer is free of logic probes, or more simply, rootkits, and your ethernet, routers are being devoid of tappings. and then the operating system, openbsd may as well be OK....

As for the harddrives - I doubt that you could go much farther than truecrypt volume inside a solid state disk with the forced erased flag option (which, when marked, will continue erasing as long as power is supplied, and will resume erasing when power resume, and cannot be stopped short of dismantling the harddrive and desoldering every flash bit)

They are not cheap, but they are there.

As for the lenovo drive, i think u need windows. (or linux, perhaps they do provide linux driver. BSD is usually out of the question)